# how do I ask for sudoku board input in python 3.X? ,I've made a sudoku solver program but it just works for the board that I declared

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
myBoard = [[0, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3],
       [2, 3, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4],
       [8, 9, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6]]
```

how to get this like an input from the user

Comment: Call `input()` nine times to get each individual line, and parse each line into a list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
myBoard = []
rows = 9
for x in range(rows):
    line = input().split(',')
    myBoard.append(line)
```

Or you can use list comprehension

```py
rows = 9
myBoard = [input().split(',') for x in range(rows)]
```

You can take comma separated input like this

```
0,4,0,7,0,0,1,3,0
0,0,2,0,0,0,6,0,0
0,0,0,4,2,0,0,0,0
6,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,3
2,3,1,0,7,0,0,8,0
4,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0
0,7,0,0,0,8,0,0,0
0,0,6,0,3,0,0,0,4
8,9,0,0,5,0,0,0,6
```